# How To Get All HTML Elements With A Specified Attribute Using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, custom-attributes

I want to create a custom attribute for my project but I am not able to do so. I searched on [Google](https://google.com) but didn't get what I wanted.

No `data-*` attributes, please...

The attributes are the ones like they are in Vue.js or Angular.js

This may seem like a stupid question but I am a beginner so please help.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Find this on Google: `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Ele when using `querySelectorAll` I will have to mention all Tag names one by one which will be very hard to do for all elements

Comment: TagName? No, you can create selectors like jQuery's `[myAttr^="Ele"]` `<--` finds elements with attr `myAttr` which value starts with `Ele`,  For exemple `<span myAttr="EleFromSO">` or `<p myAttr="EleSO">`, and so on. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks! Send It as an answer so that I can mark it as best

Comment: Done! `:)`.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

**For example:**

*This code snippet shows how to find elements with an attribute `myAttr` which value starts with `Ele`*

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[myAttr^="Ele"]'), function(elem) {
  console.log(elem.textContent);
});
```

```html
<span myAttr="EleFromSO">EleFromSO</span>
<p myAttr="EleSO">EleSO</p>
<p myAttr="SOEle">SOEle value starts with SO</p>
```

If you need to find the elements with attribute `myAttr`:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[myAttr]'), function(elem) {
  console.log(elem.getAttribute('myAttr'));
});
```

```html
<span myAttr="EleFromSO">EleFromSO</span>
<p myAttr="EleSO">EleSO</p>
<p myAttr="SOEle">SOEle value starts with SO</p>
```

Comment: But what if I wasn't knowing the value and wanted to get it by using `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @ShardulNalegave did you mean, find elements with a specific attr? for example, all elements with attrbute `myAttr` regardless of the value?

Comment: yes. I wanted all the elements so that I can find their value and do some operations on that element.

Comment: It is more than I know about JS but **Thanks For Your Help**